# iPython 3 uses Python 2 instead of Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

iPython 3 — installed with `pip3` and located at `/usr/local/bin/ipython3` — runs with Python 2.7.6 in both the console and notebook whereas I want it to run with Python 3 as it should.

This used to work fine before, but I may have reinstalled stuff using MacPorts or HomeBrew that triggered the change.

```
$ which -a python
/opt/local/bin/python  # 2.7.9
/usr/local/bin/python  # 2.7.8
/usr/local/bin/python

$ which -a python2
/usr/local/bin/python2 # 2.7.8
/usr/local/bin/python2

$ which -a python3
/usr/local/bin/python3 # 3.2.4
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ pip3 -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)

$ ipython3 -V
2.3.1
```

Comment: did you specify ipython3 to start a shell/notebook? In relation to the second part that is what happens when you install multiple interpreters.

Comment: The problem is probably because pip3 actually points to python2, remove it and reinstall using get-pip.py and the python3 interpreter

Comment: when you started an ipython3 shell previously what did you see listed as the interpreter? Also add output for `which -a  python` and `which -a  python3`

Comment: yep but add `which -a  python3`

Comment: Did you remove the system python?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm not sure what the system python is. There are some binary files for Python 2.7.8 and Python 3.4 in `/usr/local/Cellar`.

Comment: (Deleted previous comments to clean up comments.)

Comment: No worries, your path seems to be messed up. There should be a usr/bin default system python.  You must have a system  python  as ipython used 2.7.6.  try start a shell with `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @YatharthROCK `2.3.1` is the version number of IPython, please try this from the command line: `ipython3 -c 'print 1'` and judge by yourself which python version is running...
`

Comment: @gboffi I know that; and yes,`ipython3` was indeed running Python 2 before I implemented my solution below. Thanks, though.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `/usr/bin/python` indeed gives me Python 2.7.6.

Comment: do you have any entries in your .bashrc file relating to python?

Comment: To be honest I would probably just remove all bar the system python, having multiple python's installed  can leave you with these kind of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited the shebang on the iPython executable from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#/usr/local/bin/python3`, but I am not sure if this is a hacky or bad solution.

Comment: That's a fine solution, though it's unfortunate that it was necessary in the first place.

Comment: @YatharthROCK Can you explain how you did this in more detail?

Comment: @dsaxton Type `nano \`which ipython3\`` and change the first line to what is described in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

what work for me is changing #!/usr/bin/python to #! /usr/bin/python3 in file /usr/local/bin/ipython3

Just make sure that above address in all files coming out from '`whereis ipython3`' should be same.